# Is there a way to hold a leader election across Kubernetes clusters?

Tags: kubernetes, distributed-computing

All of the leader election tools like Consul, Zookeeper or any other quorum system. I've seen have been for pods within the same cluster.  I need to coordinate across clusters for a tutorial.

Comment: What leader election tools? Can you be more specific?

Comment: What is "something"?

Comment: Sorry, I phrased this poorly.  "Tutorials" is more appropriate [Leader election with kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/01/simple-leader-election-with-kubernetes/).  Alternatively, If I could get etcd or zookeeper across clusters, that would solve a lot of my issues.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer for a broad question: It's not the norm but yes you can run them in different clusters as long as you expose your containers/pods with the right ports and IP addresses and they can find each other using these ports and IP addresses.

This answer relates to quorum systems that use a consensus algorithms like [Paxos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_(computer_science)) or [Raft](https://raft.github.io/) such as [Consul](https://www.consul.io/), [Zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/), [Marathon](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/), [Chronos](https://mesos.github.io/chronos/), [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/), [Mesos](http://mesos.apache.org/), etc.

Hope it helps!